# How to limit the maximum length of the title of a node?

Tags: entities

I have a content type with a title that shouldn't be more then 10 characters long. This title field is read only.

What is the recommended way to limit the length of that title to 10 long?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module to do this.

> Maxlength allows you to set maximum length of any field on any form
>   making use of the form API. This includes fields created using the UI.
>   (Example: any text field on a node) In D6 Maxlength allows you to set
>   maximum lengths to the body, title and CCK textfields of any content
>   type (node).
>
> When the maximum length is enforced for a field, while editing content
>   of that type some Java Script will countdown how many characters are
>   left, also if the Javascript is turned off, it falls back to form API
>   validation.

[Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) : I haven't try this. Try once, hope this module solve your issue.

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.

Comment: maxlength doesn't allow to edit the node title length.I shouldn't hide the title cause  It's the most important element in this content type, and the customer will be able to add the contents.

Comment: I didn't try this, but if _maxlength doesn't allow to edit the node title length_, turn your title into a field first with the [Title project](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) then maxlength should do the job as on any other field

Comment: @Kojo its seems a good solution for my usecase, even if I fixed my issue by using field validation.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment to Nishan's answer :

if it it not possible to edit the node title length with Maxlength module, you can turn your content type nodes titles into *regular UI* fields first with the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) project.

Then [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module should do the same job as on any other field.

Comment: Note: Title project has Not support for Drupal 8

Answer (score 1):

There is now a module available that provide min/max character and word length options. It's called [Node Title Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_validation) and allows you to customize the title attributes for each Content Type independently.

[image: Node Title Validation Settings Page]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a sub module called **Property Validation** in the [field validation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation), after reading this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343628#comment-7305410).
And I added a jquery line to resize the  node title.

```
    $('.page-node-add-conteneur #edit-title').attr('size',10);
```

[image]